# register_meta not showing custom post type metabox data in rest api

Tags: plugin-development, post-meta, rest-api

I have added a custom post type and I want to expose the custom field value in the rest api. As per the docs register_meta can be used.

I have created a custom post meta box using the wordpress way. It works fine but not getting shown in the rest api. I belive that I have to pass array

[image]

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'qrcode_register_posts_meta_field' );

function qrcode_register_posts_meta_field(){
  $meta_args = array( // Validate and sanitize the meta value.
    'type'         => 'array',
    
    'description'  => 'A meta key associated with a string meta value.',
   
    'single'       => true,
   
    'show_in_rest' => array(
      'schema'=> array(
        'type'=> 'array',
        'items'=> array(
          'type'=> 'string',
        ),
      ),
    ),
);
  register_meta( 'post', 'qrcode_qr-code-type', $meta_args );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found: I forgot to enable the Custom Fields for the custom post type even if the meta boxes were programmatically created.

Comment: And how did you do that?

Comment: @markmoxx just noticed this. I was using custom post ui so I had an option there. If you coded it you might have the use the supports

Answer (score 0):

For those programmatically creating the CPT, be sure to also support 'custom-fields' in your post type, as noted in https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_meta/#user-contributed-notes

```php
register_post_type( 'book', array(
    'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'custom-fields', ...),
     // Make sure you add custom-fields here ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    )
);
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/258519)

Comment: Answer is repeat of previous answer